# Realy year datediff (no year less)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to calculate the year diferences between two dates.

Tried using DATEDIFF but that only do the less of the dates, for example:

```
Date 1: 07/03/2011
Date 2: 07/02/2012

(Date format MM/DD/YYYY)
```

Then: DATEDIFF([yyyy], '07/03/2011', '07/02/2012') = 1

But the real diferences are 0 year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since noone had a correct solution i post mine even though noone will ever notice.

```
declare @d1 datetime
declare @d2 datetime

set @d1 = '1968-02-29'
set @d2 = '2011-02-28'

select datediff(year, @d1, @d2)-
case when month(@d1)*32 + day(@d1) > month(@d2) * 32 + day(@d2) then 1 else 0 end
--case when month(@d2)*32 + day(@d1) > month(@d2) * 32 + day(@d2) then 1 else 0 end
```

This method is basically the same as the next method, difference is that it is done with numbers to avoid the casting, which i was told was slower.

```
select datediff(year, @d1, @d2)- 
case when convert(char(5),@d1, 1) > convert(char(5),@d2, 1) then 1 else 0 end
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. See my test cases - it gives 0 years between 2012-02-29 and 2013-03-01 because of the funny maths of 32 days in a month.

Comment: @RichardAkaCyberkiwi my funny maths is the same as Itzik Ben-Gan is using. Only difference is that he multiply with 100. I just saw it now.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
declare @date1 datetime
declare @date2 datetime
select @date1 = '20110703', @date2 = '20120703'

select case
    when dateadd(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, @date1, @date2), @date1) > @date2
    then DATEDIFF(yy, @date1, @date2) -1
    else DATEDIFF(yy, @date1, @date2) end
```

A fuller test case showing many edge conditions

```
create table dates(id int identity, date1 datetime, date2 datetime)
insert dates select '20110703', '20120703'
insert dates select '20110703', '20120702'
insert dates select '20110702', '20120703'
insert dates select '20110228', '20120228'
insert dates select '20120229', '20130228'
insert dates select '20120229', '20130301'
insert dates select '20110301', '20120229'
insert dates select '20120229', '20160301'
insert dates select '20120229', '20160229'
insert dates select '20101231', '20110101'
insert dates select '20100101', '20111231'

select date1, date2,
    case
    when dateadd(yy, DATEDIFF(yy, date1, date2), date1) > date2
    then DATEDIFF(yy, date1, date2) -1
    else DATEDIFF(yy, date1, date2) end
from dates
order by id
```

Comment: `DATEADD` still just adds to the datepart. It may solve the OP's issue (so +1) unless he defines years by the quantified # of days in contained years (per my answer)

Comment: @Matthew look at each case and let me know if you don't agree with the 3rd column in the output. It agrees with the "birthday" definition where a year has passed if and only if the `anniversary date` has been reached.

Comment: @cyberwiki your answer is great if using the `anniversary date` criteria (which I agree is most likely :D ) I'm just over-complicating it with varying definitions of "a year"

Comment: @Jeff - I'm well aware of how to check for leap year, but there isn't a need to.

Comment: +1 for the approach, although the overused DATEDIFF is crying out for being put into a subselect.

Comment: Your solution is not correct. It may be overkill to give you minus. For different reasons than this question, I wrote an sql very much like this one. I realized it failed and wrote the one i posted after. Your solution fails on the date in my example.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk - On the other hand, I think you have the wrong answer. The years between "last day of Feb" and "last day of Feb" between the years 1968 and 2011 is 43 in my books, not 42.

Comment: then please tell me my age at 2011-02-28 when i was born 1968-02-29

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server just does a year diff if you specify `[yyyy]`.

For `DATEDIFF([yyyy], '07/03/2011', '12/31/2011')` it will return zero.

For `DATEDIFF([yyyy], '07/03/2011', '01/01/2012')` it will return 1.

In your case you should count the days if you are looking for 365 or 366 days:

```
DATEDIFF([dd], '07/03/2011', '07/02/2012') / 366
```

Comment: The more years go by, the more inaccurate this is since it keeps taking 366 days whereas a year can have 365/366

Comment: Sure, that's why I had said "365 or 366". If you looked at the revision history, you can see it was 365. Then I changed it to be specific for JMira's example data. I can provide the full solution using conditional statements etc, but got no time for that...

Comment: Well, 365 or 366 are both equally... inaccurate

Comment: Good catch kiwi, I've fallen victim to the "not reading to the end" syndrome once again.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing the question and answers a bit more, all I've got to offer is some linkage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, `DATEDIFF` works that way with all dateparts, so I guess you should calculate the difference in days and then divide by 365 (this, if you don't care about the time of day). Si, try this:

```
DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME, @EndDate DATETIME
SET @StarDate= '20110307'
SET @EndDate = '20120207'
SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY,@StartDate, @EndDate)/365
```

Comment: He will want to first determine the number of days in a year. For 2012, per his example, 365 won't work. Also, he needs to check whether his included dates include Feb 29th for leap years.